# Resolving an error when adding users and assigning groups from a csv file

Tags: bash

So I have been working on this issue for a bit and I am completely confused.  I have a csv file that contains group, firstname, lastname, username.  I am trying to write a script that first checks to see if the user exists. If the user exists, then it would only add the group to that user.  If the user doesn't exist, it would add the user, create a home directory only accessible by them, assign them the primary group of students, and add them to a secondary group which is specified in the csv file.

Here is an example of what the data looks like in the csv file:

```
csc150,Brion,Fontes,brionf
csc150,Dru,Glenn,drug
csc250,Brion,Fontes,brionf
```

I have now ran my code though shellcheck.net.  It said I had a few issues so I corrected them.  My script is now this:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/root/users/users.csv
IFS=","
[ ! -f "$INPUT" ] &while read -r f1 f4
do getent passwd "$f4" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$f4" -eq 0 ]
then
usermod -a -G "$f1 $f4"
elif [ "$f4" -eq 1 ]
then
useradd -m -d/home/"$f4 $f4" -g students -G "$f1"
fi
done < users.csv
```

All groups have been created and show up with cat /etc/group

It should be noted that all user information here is fictitious so no ones personal data is being tossed out here.  I am running Debian on a VM.  Here is the error I get when running the script:

```
./useradd.sh: line 6: [: firstname,lastname,username: integer expression expected
./useradd.sh: line 9: [: firstname,lastname,username: integer expression expected
```

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary images, [edit] your question with the formatted text instead. Regardless of that, just leave a white space after `[` on line 6. https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I miss typed the code as I did have a space between the [ "f$4" on line 6.  I also edited the post to remove the image.